# Ambiguous use of "asset" in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

i wrote a program to get notified about when video player comes up on the screen and get things out of that. The code was working on Swift 2 but now it's Swift 3.0 and it's not working. It says "ambiguous use of asset". Look at my code:

```
func VideoPlayedInFullscreen(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let player = aNotification.object
        if player == nil {
            return
        }
         //this line below shows ambiguous use of asset error
        let ast = (player as! AnyObject).asset 
}
```

I will be very mcuh thankful to you. Please help

Comment: Why are you casting to `AnyObject`? Do you *really* want message dispatch? Almost certainly you meant to cast to a specific type that has an `asset` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler – as I am – is clueless what type `player` is. Tell the compiler the type by casting it to the actual type.

I guess – after looking into the documentation – it's `AVPlayerItem` so the code is supposed to be:

```
func VideoPlayedInFullscreen(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        guard let player = aNotification.object as? AVPlayerItem else { return }

        let ast = player.asset 
}
```

In Swift use `if - let` or `guard - let` rather than simply check for `nil`. The benefit ist you get the object unwrapped on success.

Comment: Thanks a lot #vadian. Your answer helped me resolving the issue. Thanks again. This is the first time on stackoverflow when i found an answer i didn't have to change a bit even. You are amazing :)